# UglifyJS Running out of Memory

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, ffmpeg, uglifyjs

I'm trying to minify a 24MB JavaScript file, but after about 10 minutes of runtime, the script exits with an error about running out of memory. Are there any flags that can help? I'm running Windows 7 64-bit with 16GB physical memory.

```
C:\projects\test\js>uglifyjs -o ffmpeg.min.js ffmpeg.js
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
"scripts": {
    "ugly": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs ffmpeg.js -c -o ffmpeg.min.js"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks it works! It still used about 1.6G of ram to uglify a largish (22M) file though. Computers with limited memory still might have issues...

Comment: What if I'm using a command like "webpack-dev-server --port=8888"?

Comment: Yes please feel free to modify the size as needed!